# How can I fix the spacing between MS Word text without retyping?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have copied text from a txt file but I have a problem with how the spacing looks

[image: word document snap]

1. Shows the text after I remove all formatting
2. Shows the text as it looks when I type with the same font.

I have tried [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-spaces-between-text-e9b96011-1c42-45c0-ad8f-e8a6e4a33462) but it does not change the text. I have a whole document that I need to fix without typing again. How can I do this?

Comment: You say you have tried changing the character spacing, but what is the current setting for the text that spaced?  Does it say that the current character spacing is normal?

Comment: @Paul yes it is set to Normal.

Comment: Perhaps the original text includes actual spaces or invisible characters between the letters? Try showing all characters (`CTRL+*`).